# Grid with Buttons

Tags: java, javafx

I need to print out a grid in a windows and I need button under the grid. So that I can control the action on the grid, but at the moment I don't get the grid printed out only the buttons

```
// Create and initialize cell
public Cell[][] cell = new Cell[rows][cols];

protected BorderPane getPane() {
    HBox paneForButtons = new HBox(20);
    //button start
    startB.setOnAction(e -> {
        if( startB.isPressed() == false){
            System.out.println("start");
        }
    });


    //button stop
    stopB.setOnAction(e -> {
        if( stopB.isPressed() == false){
            System.out.println("stop");
        }
    });

    //button left
    leftB.setOnAction(e -> text.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(-rotate, text.getX(), text.getY())));

    //button right
    rightB.setOnAction(e -> text.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(rotate, text.getX(), text.getY())));

    //fiel to get the moves
    moveFeld.setPromptText("1,2 or 3 steps");
    Button absenden = new Button();
    absenden.setOnAction(e -> {
        ReadInput2();
        if( moveFeld.getText() != null && !moveFeld.getText().isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Moves are " + moveFeld.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    absenden.setText("enter");

    paneForButtons.getChildren().addAll(startB, stopB, leftB, rightB, moveFeld, absenden);
    paneForButtons.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    paneForButtons.setStyle("-fx-border-color: green");


    BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
    pane.setBottom(paneForButtons);
    //pane.setBottom(paneForButtons);

    // Pane to hold cell
    GridPane pane2 = new GridPane();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            pane2.add(cell[i][j] = new Cell(), j, i);

    pane2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    pane.setCenter(pane2);

    return pane;
}

public static class Cell extends Pane {

    public Cell() {
        setStyle("-fx-border-color: black");
        this.setPrefSize(800, 800);
    }

}
```

I'm calling the method `getPane` in my void so I think there is not problem with that you guys have any idea how I get the grid above my buttons.
Now to part two the grid can be painted however the user wants I putted in 5 for now but in the future it should be mutable

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: Why not use buttons border as a grid ?

Comment: the grid have to be a grid of lines